# Why is this Union Query not working

Tags: php, mysql, database, wordpress

I am trying to access multiple tables from mySQL via my php in wordpress. My code looks like this...

```
function retrieve_libraries( $data ) {
    $second_db = new wpdb(DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, "saic3_LibraryIndex", DB_HOST);
    $query = "SELECT * FROM `Library` WHERE library_id=74 UNION SELECT  * FROM `Library_Collection` WHERE library_id=74";
    $list = $second_db->get_results($query);
    return $list;
}
```

Before I had my query like this...

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM `Library` WHERE library_id=74"
```

And the data returned just fine. I have been looking into the UNION statement and the UNION ALL and both seem to not work. Am I calling this wrong? is my syntax off? Asking for a friend.

Comment: the query works on the db?

Comment: Are the tables union-compatible?

Comment: @Spizzi The second one listed works but when I try to add the union it returns an empty array

Comment: did you tried the query directly on the DB?maybe the tables are not compatible...

Comment: @apokryfos not sure how to check that. From what it seems probably not. They each work individually but not with the union

Comment: both of this tables must have similar columns . have they ?

Comment: same number of columns and compatible data type for the union otherwise you need a join...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`UNION` isn't going to work unless `Library` and `Library_Collection` have the same number and type of columns.

Based on the table names*, it looks like you probably want to JOIN the two tables instead of UNION them.

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM `Library`
          LEFT JOIN `Library_Collection`
             ON Library.library_id = Library_Collection.library_id
          WHERE Library.library_id=74";
```

*<sub>(I'm assuming Library_Collection is the things a Library has.)</sub>

Comment: Ok so join is the correct way to go about it my mistake. This statement works for me up until the where. If I add in that last WHERE statement it breaks.. and I know for sure the id 74 exists.

Comment: nevermind the WHERE statement does work. I think I was testing the wrong file